# What is different between $this-> and parent:: in OOP PHP?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, super

I code something like this to give you an example

This is using "$this->"

```
<?php
class A{
    public function example(){
        echo "A";
    }
}

class B extends A{
    public function example2(){
        $this->example();
    }
}

$b = new B();

echo $b->example2();
?>
```

and This is using parent::

```
<?php
class A{
    public function example(){
        echo "A";
    }
}

class B extends A{
    public function example2(){
        parent::example();
    }
}

$b = new B();

echo $b->example2();
?>
```

What is different between $this-> and parent:: in OOP PHP?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference is that you can access a function of a base class and not of the currient implementation.

```
class A {
    public function example() {
        echo "A";
    }

    public function foo() {
        $this->example();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function example() {
        echo "B";
    }

    public function bar() {
        parent::example();
    }
}
```

And here some tests:

```
$a=new A();
$a->example(); // echos A
$a->foo();     // echos A

$b=new B();
$b->example(); // echos B
$b->foo();     // echos B
$b->bar();     // echos A
```

Answer (score 6):

`parent::example()` calls the parent class method, where `$this->example()` call the current class method.

In your example there's no difference, since class `B` doesn't override `example()` method. It is common to write something like this (maybe it will help you to understand better this concept):

```
    class A {

       public function example(){
           echo 'A';
       }
    }

    class B extends A {

       public function example(){
           echo 'B';
       }

       public function example2(){
          $this->example();
       }


       public function example3() {
          parent::example();
       }
   }

$b = new B();

$b->example2();//print B

$b->example3();//print A
```

Answer (score 3):

In simple words

**$this** is an **instance reference**, so whenever you use **$this** it starts referencing current class methods and properties.

**parent** is a **parent reference** which can be used to access parent class properties and methods with public or protected access modifier.

Comment: _**parent** is a **parent reference** which can be used to access parent class properties and methods_.. as long as they are _protected_ or _pubic_ ;)

Answer (score 1):

`parent::` will call a method or an attribute of the parent. However, since this is refering to the class and not any kind of instance, you can only call a static method or attribute.
`$this->` refers to the current instance of the object you call this in.

You could also want to refer to `self::` which refers to the current class (once again, no instance involved here) within an object or a static method.

Comment: `parent::` it's not used to call static method only.

Comment: could you check that parent can only be called on static methods? Calling parent on dynamic methods works and is described in the php doc https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php